# how to inject mock without using @injectmocks

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking, mockito

I have the following class

```
public class One {
    private Map<String, String> nodes = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public void addNode(String node, String nodefield){
        this.nodes.put(node, nodefield);
    }
}
```

I want to write a test class to test the addNode method and have the following:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class OneTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private One one = new One();

    @Mock
    Map<String, String> nodes;

    @Test
    public void testAddNode(){
        one.addNode("mockNode", "mockNodeField");
        Mockito.verify(nodes).put("mockNode","mockNodeField");
    }
}
```

which works. But I was wondering if there is a way to do it without using @InjectMocks like the following

```
public class OneTest {

    private One one;

    @Test
    public void testAddNode(){
        Map<String, String> nodes = Mockito.mock(Map.class);

        one = Mockito.injectmocks(One.class, nodes); // or whatever equivalent methods are

        one.addNode("mockNode", "mockNodeField");
        Mockito.verify(nodes).put("mockNode","mockNodeField");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out by using PowerMockito instead of normal Mockito.

```
public class OneTest {

    private One one;

    @Test
    public void testAddNode(){
        HashMap nodes = PowerMockito.mock(HashMap.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(HashMap.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(nodes);


        One one = new One(); 

        one.addNode("mockNode", "mockNodeField");
        Mockito.verify(nodes).put("mockNode","mockNodeField");
    }
}
```

However, I don't really know what PowerMockito does that Mockito doesn't do to make it work though.

Comment: what you really need is a reflection utility to get access to the private property. Once you get access to them then you can use spy or mock. Spy is better as you just want to focus on one instance. Mockito had internal class Whitebox if you still using 1.x version. Spring has ReflectionUtil if you happen to use Spring.

Comment: I recently revisited the problem and found ReflectionTestUtils was a better solution. I found a good reading here and would like to share: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/09/private-spring-dependency-injections.html. I'm trying to stay away from PowerMock because I read that it's not the best practice. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

How about change the class by injecting the map as a dependency? This makes it easier to test and gives you the added benefit of being able to use an implementation of the Map interface, for example:

```
  public class One {

    private Map<String, String> nodes;

    public One(Map<String, String> nodes) {

        this.nodes = nodes;

    }

    public void addNode(String node, String nodefield){

        this.nodes.put(node, nodefield);

    }
}
```

Then to test:

```
Map mockMap = Mockito.mock(Map.class);

One one = new One(mockMap);

one.addNode("mockNode", "mockNodeField");

Mockito.verify(mockMap).put("mockNode","mockNodeField");
```

Comment: Yeah I thought of that too. But I am actually writing a test for a class that wasn't written by me. The class already has a constructor set up. The above code was just a simpler version of the actual class for explanation. So is there no way to write a test for the addNode method without changing the original class?